# The bundle uses a bundle name or display name associated with an Apple app

Tags: ios, validation, app-store, info.plist

[image: Error message during validation]

When submitting my app to the app store for upgrade, I got a validation warning stating that my app could not have the same bundle display name as an Apple app.

---

A clever way to get aground this is to add a special character to the end of your bundle display name. For example: Compass can be Compass!, Compass+, Compass.

Yahoo! Weather has a neat bullet point dot after their bundle display name. Any one know how to add that character to your bundle display name?

Comment: What is your bundle name or display name?

Comment: My bundle display name is Compass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A clever way to solve this is to add a special character to the end of your bundle display name. For example: Compass can be Compass!, Compass+, Compass.

Yahoo! Weather has a neat bullet point dot after their bundle display name. Any one know how to add that character to your bundle display name?

Comment: ChrisF, this is a perfectly good answer. And the only solution. Please don't delete.