# Trying to re-upload app compilation to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

Alright, I'm trying to upload my first app to the App Store, at first it got rejected due to a simple bug, But I can't figure out how to re upload the fixed version to iTunes Connect. When I try to send it through Xcode ou Application Loader, I get the following error:

```
The bundle uses a bundle name or display name that is already taken.
```

The app's version is 1.0, the build number is 1. I can't figure out how to replace the older rejected compilation with the new one. Every time I try sending a new compilation, I get this error. I already tried changing the app's version and bundle numbers. I also can't make a new version or even delete the app from iTunes Connect.

I'm using Xcode 9.
I probably rejected the rejected build, so the app's status is "ready to send" again, like in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have mentioned, does not seem to be about the version, but rather the app name. Its been asked and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813726/invalid-binary-error-the-bundle-uses-a-bundle-name-or-display-name-associated-w) [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703608/the-bundle-uses-a-bundle-name-or-display-name-associated-with-an-apple-app)

For versioning : 
Read the [Technical note on Version Numbers and Build Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html).

Specifically :

> For every new build you submit, you will need to invent a new build
>   number whose value is greater than the last build number you used (for
>   that same version).

You you will **have** to bump your build number.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the app's name (Display name)! Looks like that if you compile it with a different display name than what's on iTunes Connect, it will get you that error!